# Check Status of JavaScript via .JSP page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, if-statement

**Background:** My client has a sitemap that uses an accordion menu for the layout. (no talking them out of it). They are afraid SiteBots that do not use JS to view a page will not see the links hidden by the accordion.

**Question:** I know about the `<noscrpit`> tag but is there a way to programmatically write an `if statement` on a .jsp page that can check to see if Javascript is enabled?

This way I can server a different sitemap layout depending on how the page is being viewed.

Comment: JSP runs on the server, so there's no way it can directly know if the client viewing its output has JS enabled or not

Comment: I was afraid of that I just wasn't sure. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Maybe you can send some ajax request to server which will indicate whether js is enabled or not, and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*@Rory-McCrossan is right*

**For other wanderers looking for an answer**
It is not possible. JSP is a Server-Side language, It can't know settings of a client's browser. If it could do that, It would be a huge security risk for the clients. This is why the `<noscript>` exists.

You need to execute Java only if `noscript` tag is triggered, but regardless of that tag, Java will always get executed. So, this can't be done.

```
<noscript>
    <% 
       // java if-statement in here, 
       // which will get executed everytime whether JavaScript is enabled/disabled.
    %>
</noscript>
```